# Understanding how Public Properties are set in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, properties

I am trying to understand how a value in a Public property is set. There does not seem to be anything passed or any kind of lookup.

```
Public Shared Property IsUser() As String
    Get
        If HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUser") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUser").ToString()
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUser") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I have tried searching for the ClassName i.e. `UserSession.IsUser =` and also the only place the session value is set is in the property. HttpContext.Current.Session("IsUser") = value

What do I need to understand better.. I mean at the end of the day the User has to be True or False so where is the Lookup or passed parameter?

Comment: The passed parameter is `value`, so somewehere there is `SomeClass.IsUser = SomeString`(shoukld be a `Boolean` instead of `String`). You just have to read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Comment out that property and run the program. It won't compile or crash where ever it's using it.